# Gradle configurations not building as expected

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have two configurations - compile and stub - compile is as you would expect and stub is identical to compile but it will substitute a dependency in compile (I have hidden most dependencies) :

```
configurations {
    stub
    stub.extendsFrom compile
    stub.exclude module: "thelibrary"
    }

dependencies {
    compile(name: "thelibrary")
    compile project(":lib:project")

    stub files('./libs/thelibrary.jar')
}
```

When I do 'gradle build' all dependencies are pulled and the jar is built properly ( taking ~25seconds).

The issue is when I do 'gradle buildstub' (building with configuration) - no dependencies are pulled, nothing is built and it's like as if it ignored 'stub.extendsFrom compile' (takes ~3 seconds).

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:

The task to create the stub jar ("thelibrary.jar"):

```
task StubJar(type: Jar){
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.XXXXXX.stub'
}
baseName = 'thelibrary'
from 'src/main/java/com/XXXXXX/stub'
}
```

Gradle output of gradle buildstub:

```
:lib:xxxxxxx:buildstub UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.741 secs
```

Comment: How is the buildstub task defined? What's the gradle output?

Comment: Updated original question with requested information.

Comment: You posted the definition of the task StubJar. But the task you execute is buildoamStub. What is this task? How is it defined?

Comment: I do not have a task for buildstub - I have a configuration called stub and I am trying to build that. I want my configuration to be exactly as compile -except one library has been substituted.                    If you type in 'gradle tasks' it says to build using a configuration do the following : "Rules
-----
Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
"

Comment: The build<ConfigurationName> tasks build the **artefacts** belonging to the configuration. You haven't declared any artefact for the stub configuration. Read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html for an explanation of what the task does, and how artefacts are defined. The task doesn't do what you think it does. It's not at all the same thing as the build tasks where compile would be replaced by stub.

Comment: It does not seem like configurations are the best way to substitute libraries, based on a command line input. I think I will create a task that substitutes the libraries instead.